# Firebase + js (angular) change online state when leave window

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hey I'm trying to establish an attribute stateOnline for each user for my web app (angular 5 + firebase).
I saw few things on Android and I tried to implement something for me:

```
  signInUser(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
          () => {
            this.setOnlineState(true);
            resolve();
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

  signOutUser() {
    this.setOnlineState(false);
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }

  setOnlineState(state: boolean) {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    firebase.database().ref("users/" + currentUser.uid).update({ onlineState: state });
  }
```

It's working fine when the user click on buttons calling signIn and signOut but if he leaves the page without clicking on signOut, onlineState will stay on true ! How can I correct this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **onbeforeunload** Event:

[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

HTML:

```
<div (window:beforeunload)="doSignOff()"></div>
```

TS:

```
  doSignOff(){
    this.setOnlineState(false);

    //If you want to make sign out.
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
```

Comment: I have one problem using that. When the page is refreshed it logged off the user !